# Join two tables with a partial match to an exact match

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Confusing title i know. I am trying to join two tables:

**Table: ITEM**

```
+---------------+
|  ItemName     |
+---------------+
| "Banana"      |
| "~A Apple"    |
| "~B Orange"   |
| "Banana ~C"   |
| "Apple ~CC"   |
+---------------+
```

**Table: CODELOOKUP**

```
+-------+------------+
| Code  | CodeResult |
+-------+------------+
| "~A"  | "One"      |
| "~B"  | "Two"      |
| "~C"  | "Three"    |
| "~CC" | "Four"     |
+-------+------------+
```

I wish to join these tables showing all the items in the `ITEM` table, and if the `ItemName` contains a `"~"` followed by a combination of letters located anywhere in the `ItemName` (but will never run into another word - it will always be at the start, the end or in the middle of mutiple words with spaces either side) I want it to relate to the `CodeResult` value. So a **PARTIAL MATCH** in the `ItemName` to an **EXACT MATCH** in `CodeResult`.

I managed to get the below code:

```
SELECT ITEM.*, CODELOOKUP.CodeResult  
FROM ITEM LEFT JOIN CODELOOKUP ON INSTR(ITEM.ItemName, CODELOOKUP.Code)
```

This returned almost what I am after, the only issue is that it returned the row `"Apple ~CC"` twice with:

```
+-------------+---------+
| "Banana"    | ""      |
| "~A Apple"  | "One"   |
| "~B Orange" | "Two"   |
| "Banana ~C" | "Three" |
| "Apple ~CC" | "Three" |
| "Apple ~CC" | "Four"  |
+-------------+---------+
```

...where it should only return the row with the exact match being the one with `"Four"` like:

```
+-------------+---------+
| "Banana"    | ""      |
| "~A Apple"  | "One"   |
| "~B Orange" | "Two"   |
| "Banana ~C" | "Three" |
| "Apple ~CC" | "Four"  |
+-------------+---------+
```

What is the way to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join only on partial matches with a space following them, and append a space at the end of the string, to avoid `~C` matching `~CC`:

```
SELECT ITEM.*, CODELOOKUP.CodeResult
FROM ITEM LEFT JOIN CODELOOKUP ON INSTR(ITEM.ItemName & " ",CODELOOKUP.Code & " ")
```